# How to convert quantized ONNX model to quantized TFLite model?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow-lite, onnx, quantization

I have quantized ONNX model (exported from PyTorch). Is there any way to convert it to quantized TFLite model? It's important to apply quantization on the PyTorch side.

Comment: did you check - https://siliconlabs.github.io/mltk/mltk/tutorials/onnx_to_tflite.html

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work because OpenVino intermediate format uses FP32/FP16 precision. And with this approach, quantization is done at OpenVino -> TFLite conversion